# How to implement Oracle's "func(...) keep (dense_rank ...)" In Hive

Tags: oracle, hive, hiveql

I have a table abcd in Oracle DB

```
  +-------------+----------+
  | abcd.speed  | abcd.ab  |
  +-------------+----------+
  | 4.0         | 2        |
  | 4.0         | 2        |
  | 7.0         | 2        |
  | 7.0         | 2        |
  | 8.0         | 1        |
  +-------------+----------+
```

And I'm using a query like this:

```
select min(speed) keep (dense_rank last order by abcd.ab NULLS FIRST) MOD from abcd;
```

I'm trying to convert the code to Hive, but it looks like `keep` is not available in Hive.
Could you suggest an equivalent statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  -max(struct(ab,-speed)).col2 as mod
from    abcd
;
```

---

```
+------+
| mod  |
+------+
| 4.0  |
+------+
```

---

Let start by explaining `min(speed) keep (dense_rank last order by abcd.ab NULLS FIRST)`:
Find the row(s) with the max value of `ab`.
For this/those row(s), find the min value of `speed`.

We are using 2 tricks here.
The 1st is based on the ability to get the max value of a struct.
`max(struct(c1,c2,c3,...))` returns the same result as if you have sorted the structs by `c1`, then by `c2`, then by `c3` etc. and then chose the last element.

The 2nd trick is to use `-speed` (which is the same of `-1*speed`).
Finding the max of `-speed` and then taking the minus of that value (which gives us `speed`), is the same of finding the min of `speed`.

If we would have ordered the structs, it would have looked like this (since 2 is bigger than 1 and -4 is bigger than -7):

```
+----+-------+
| ab | speed |
+----+-------+
|  1 |  -8.0 |
|  2 |  -7.0 |
|  2 |  -7.0 |
|  2 |  -4.0 |
|  2 |  -4.0 |
+----+-------+
```

The last struct in this case in `struct(2,-4.0)`, therefore this is the result of the `max` function.
The fields names for a struct are `col1`, `col2`, `col3` etc., so
`struct(2,-4.0).col2` is `-4.0`. and preceding it with minus (which is the same as multiple it by -1) as in `-struct(2,-4.0).col2` is `4.0`.

Comment: IS there any specific reason to add "-" symbol. Even following query is also giving similar result.   select  max(struct(ab,speed)).col2 as mod from abcd;

Comment: Without the minus sign it will be the equivalent to `max(speed) keep (...)`. The result would be `7.0`

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, in the question the query uses `min`, but your answer uses `max`, is that on purpose?

Comment: @HenriqueBrisola (1) As you can see, my code returns the correct result, for a representative data sample (2) Note the minus sign preceding `speed`

Comment: I noted, but I don't know enough of SQL to really understand what is going on, I was hoping for an explanation.

Comment: @HenriqueBrisola - I added explanation to the solution